# How to list my questions

Tags: discussion

I'm a newbie in stackexchange and don't have meta privileges. But I would like to know what command or steps to do in order to list the questions I've asked previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply click [this URL](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions):

To get there in the future, go to your user account in the top, black bar then click the questions tab. Make sure you are on the [Main Site](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) before you click your username.

Comment: the link broken? or only available to OP?

Comment: @Ravan typo, fixed. Should go to the person who clicks it's page.

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question

Answer (score 1):

You just need to search for [user:william-pabón](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Awilliam-pab%C3%B3n). You can view more tips like this on the search page under "Advanced Search Tips".

Answer (score 0):

Click your gravatar on the top bar, then on the freshly loaded profile page select "activity" tab and then "questions" tab.

Comment: There is no need for him to click activity on his own profile. That shows by default to him.